# zombie.browser.fire does not trigger the helper

Tags: meteor, zombie.js

Zombie does not trigger events when you fill inputs. But you can trigger those events with `zombie.browser.fire("selector", "event")`

but the event does not fire with Meteor.

here is how my events are defined:

```
  Template.hello.events(
  {
     'change #name': function () {
        console.log("changing the name");
        Session.set("name", $("#name").val());
     }
  });
```

the template does work nicely in the browser but not with `zombie`

Answer (score 0):

it appears that zombie has problems firing events with `fire` in certain conditions: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/181

the work around is to use `browser.evaluate "$('#target-selector').click()"`